# BlySky Statistics - File naming conventions

Tags: r

When opening file 'TestFile.RData' in BlueSky Statistics it is opened with this name PLUS Dataset3 attached. Looks like this in tab TestFile.RData(Dataset3)
I would like to use my original name when using r code in the r command editor but from what I see BlueSky wants me to use the Dataset3 name.
Please clarify this file name issue for me.

If my original name is changed I see issues with reproducing things - as the given name of Dataset3 is not controllable.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Your observation is correct. When ever a file is opened in BlueSky Statistics (that is not an R datafile) we create a dataframe object in R. We name these objects sequentially namely Dataset1, Dataset2,Dataset3, etc. We could always use the name of the original file, however we went with Dataset1,Dataset2,Dataset3 for compatibility with SPSS. Many of our users come from SPSS and that is exactly what SPSS does. There is a simple work around, see below.

To work around this you need to change the default code we use to open the dataset. To see the code in the output window, Go to the top level menu Tools , Tools->Configuration settings->Select the Output tab and select the checkbox near the text "Show syntax in output window"

The code you will see when you open a dataset in the output Window is 
BSkyloadDataset(fullpathfilename='C:/Users/Aaron_2/Documents/BlueSky Statistics/Sample Datasets/IRT/engagement.csv', filetype='CSV', worksheetName='',load.missing=FALSE, character.to.factor=FALSE, csvHeader=TRUE, isBasketData=FALSE, trimSPSStrailing=FALSE, sepChar=',', deciChar='.', datasetName='Dataset2')

All you need to do is change the datasetName parameter to the name you want to use

I will also add an enhancement to make the default behavior of naming the dataset when opening files to be the name of the file. This is easy to do.

With R datasets this is not a problem because we load all dataframe objects into the grid. The name of the dataset in the grid, continues to be the dataset object

Answer (score 0):

BlueSky is one of the few packages that use R and allow you to open and work on multiple data files at once. This naming approach is its way of allowing that while using files that have not yet been stored as R data files (.RData). After importing data from a non-R file, simply use "File> Save as" and save it as an R Object (.RData). The next time you open that file, it will maintain the name you've given it.